# IOC/Unity and reference problems in legacy system

Tags: .net, architecture, interface, unity-container

I have some long term concerns concerning object creation in our system.
We currently have thousands of business classes in our product, which contains database mappings (save,load,delete methods in hard coded sql) and also some business rules. These classes are in multiple assemblies, but they are all located in one "product" boundary (one trunk in versioncontrol).

Now we have separated some part of our system into modules. These modules cannot refer product assemblies, but will need some of the business classes in them.

Example of structure

I have a product assembly called customer and a class called CompanyCustomer

Then i have a module assembly called Booking which has class BookingManager. In BookingManager i need to use CompanyCustomer, load it from database and read few properties from it.

I have now created interface IBookingManagerCompanyCustomer, implemented that interface in CompanyCustomer (because Customer assembly can refer Booking assembly, not vice a versa). Then I'm creating objects using Unity by resolving implementation for that interface.

Is this a good idea or would you sugges some other method?

I'm little concerned about creating businessclasses with unity. This method also leads to creation of unnecessary interfaces, because all modules which need CompanyCustomer has to add their own interface for this class and class has to implemented all these interfaces. So basicly CompanyCustomer will implement as many interface as we have modules in our product.

Comment: Why not just ICompanyCustomer instead of IBookingManagerCompanyCustomer?

Comment: I have multiple modules. One is called Booking, other one is called CA. So if I declare ICompanyCustomer in Booking assembly and also in CA assembly, i cannot implement both in my product assembly.

Also i cannot add ICompanyCustomer interface into product, because Booking assembly cannot refer product assembly.

Comment: Make a new Assembly and add the interfaces there, and reference it from both. Better than writing lots of more code to have quasi-identical interfaces for everything.

Comment: My modules are brought into product solution via svn external and they dont have any shared assemblies which they could refer. Also if I create one assembly, add all interfaces into that assembly and bring that assembly into product, I would have to add that assembly into all other products i have.

This will lead to maintenance hell, because when that interface changes, i have to fix all the other products also because they wont  compile anymore (their CompanyCustomers wont implement all the features added in interface)

Comment: That is independent. If ISomeCompanyCustomer changes, ISomeOtherCompanyCustomer will be affected too, because the CompanyCustomer class will have to implement both interfaces. I think it's hell to want to maintain lots of different interfaces for the same functionality in the same class that are duplicates except for the namespace...

Comment: i agreed about that, thats why im searching for easier solution.